# Does WaitCommEvent() report data that has already been received?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I have a program that performs overlapped I/O on a serial port and I am seeing cases where data that has been received is not being read by the application.  My code is using `SetCommMask()` and `WaitCommEvent()` as follows:

```
if(!waiting_for_comm_event)
{
   comm_event_ready = false;
   if(!SetCommMask(port_handle, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR | EV_RLSD))
      throw OsException(my_strings[strid_set_comm_mask_failed].c_str());
   rcd = WaitCommEvent(port_handle, &event_mask, &event_control);
   last_error = GetLastError();
   if(rcd && event_mask != 0)
       comm_event_ready = true;
   else if(last_error != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
       throw OsException(my_strings[strid_wait_comm_event_failed].c_str());
   else
       waiting_for_comm_event = true;
  }
```

This code is invoked after I have written any data in my output buffer.  There is a possibility that data could be received while this writing is taking place.  Will `WaitCommEvent()` report the condition where there is already data waiting to be read?

Comment: My research suggests that `EV_RXCHAR` is edge-triggered.  You really want to use `ReadFile` to detect incoming characters that may have already been transferred.

Comment: I found that I can use ClearCommError() to determine if there is data waiting to be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to ask here, you don't want to know the answer.

No, really -- it means you're relying on undocumented behavior that could change in future Windows versions.

You can instead use overlapped I/O to start tracking incoming data and events before you send the data that triggers them.

Two approaches (I use a `ReadFileEx` variant of the first in my own serial code):

- Issue a background (overlapped) read.
- Issue a background (overlapped) `WaitCommEvent`.
- Write the data.
- Wait on both background operations... completion of either one will cause `WaitForMultipleEvents` to proceed.

or

- Issue a background (overlapped) `WaitCommEvent`.
- Write the data.
- Wait on the background operation.
- If the wake event was receipt of data, read it.

In either case, incoming data and errors, even before `WriteFile` completes, will be detected.

Comment: The key to your statement is your statement, "before you send the data that triggers them".  The protocol that I need to support has asynchronous reads and writes.  The device can write without me initiating that write.

Comment: @Jon: Mine too.  And what I do is leave an overlapped read in progress, always.